Hive Flutter Error with storage_backend_js
Everything worked fine and hive saved and loaded everything but then I started getting this message. And I don't know how to fix it.
I've tried adding new type filed to hive adapter and after that this message started showing.
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/hive-2.2.3/lib/src/backend/js/native/storage_backend_js.dart:18:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'StorageBackendJs' is missing implementations for these members:
 - StorageBackend.writeFrames

I tried deleting all new code but the message keeps showing

I fixed this error by going to .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/ (you need to open hidden folders for that on your OS) and deleting hive folders. Then I reinstalled all dependancies and everything went back to normal.
